# class DuplicateItemException is public, should be declared in a file named DuplicateItemException.java

Tags: java, applet

Why am I getting this error "class DuplicateItemException is public, should be declared in a file named DuplicateItemException.java", when I try to compile?
Can anyone help me through this?

Comment: Because you didn't do what the error told you to do? If you want help, you will have to tell us why you think you don't deserve this messsage; is your class in a file with that name?

Answer (score 2):

Java convention is that a class is placed in a file with the same name of the class, so I assume your class `DuplicateItemException` is not placed in a file named `DuplicateItemException.java`.

Comment: Well, not "convention."  It's a requirement.  But, yes this.